# Package tools and dependencies into installer

Tags: development-environment, dependency-management

Anyone come across a utility to package existing installers into a single installer package? I'm upgrading an existing project from  vs2008/v3.5 to vs2010/v4.0 and the tools and general dependencies must be updated/installed for each developer. It would be great if I could package the different tools, API's og environment dependencies into a single setup file (not batch/script). Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

/Jasper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not many responses, although I'm quite sure that many face the same problems. So far I've scripted all the dependencies, tools and configurations in a 'simple' unattended batch script and so far it seems to work just fine - Note none have upgraded to the new toolchain I'm imposing on the development team :)
I mostly just invoke msi's, install and configure Oracle ODP.NET and a couple of visual studio plugins - all by using silent option on the different installer types. E.g.

```
MSIEXEC.EXE /I "Windows Identity Foundation Runtime 6.1 64bit\Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu" /QB- /LWAMOE c:\temp\install.log ALLUSERS=1
```

and

```
"%vsixInstaller%" /quiet /skuName:Ultimate "Web Service Software Factory 2010\WSSF2010.vsix"
```

Still need to script the certificate installation and configuration and I'm thinking of getting everthing into source control and just provide new users with a binary which can check out everything to a workspace (TFS) and run the installation.

If anyone have has comments to this approach and/or alternatives, please answer/comment. I believe this is one of many key features when trying to become more agile and automate as much as possible.